# Django – Use a template tag within a template tag?

Tags: python, django, templates, django-models, django-templates

I am trying to write a simple Django view that prints out a table representing all the fields in a model.

I have a model called Menu_Items, with 6 fields:

```
Item_Id
Name
Description
Base_Price
Image_Path
Item_Tags
```

Using `Menu_Items._meta.fields` I can retrieve the list of fields.

For a given queryset (e.g. `Menu_Items.objects.all()`) I would like to print out all of the fields, formatted as a table.

I've tried passing the fields in the context, but I cannot figure out which template tag to use. Is it possible to use a template tag inside of a template tag? like so:

```
{% for field in fields %}
    {{ menuItems.0.{{ field.name }} }}
    {{ field.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

In this case, the field is each of the fields returned by Menu_Items._meta.fields

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of doing this, change your query so it returns a `ValueQuerySet` with [`values()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values).

Your result will be a list of dictionaries, here is an example from the documentation:

```
>>> Blog.objects.filter(name__startswith='Beatles').values()
[{'id': 1, 'name': 'Beatles Blog', 'tagline': 'All the latest Beatles news.'}]
```

Now, in your template:

```
{% for item in results %}
   {% for column,value in item.iteritems %}
       {{ column }} {{ value }}
   {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

This will result in:

```
id 1
name Beatles Blog
tagline All the latest Beatles news.
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, with one small change. I used "iteritems" instead of "itervalues". Thank you so much!

My final code:

    `{% for result in results %}

     {% for field,value in result.iteritems %}

      {{field}} : {{value}}<br>

     {% endfor %}

    {% endfor %}`